# Can we execute mutiple commands in the same command prompt launched by python script?

Tags: python, windows

I have used `os.system(command)` in a for loop.

By using this, CMD opens, executes the command and close. For Second command, CMD opens again, executes tha command and close. Due to this, CMD pop-ups again and again.

Meanwhile, I am not able to do another task on system. I want to do this in a CMD so that i can minimize it and continue with other task.

Comment: Why not use `subprocess.call()` to run your subprocesses without using `cmd` at all?

Answer (score 2):

You can just concatenate your commands, delimited by a semicolon (`;`) and only call `os.system` once.

Comment: @danihp no, but in windows you can use `&&` instead.

Comment: Commands are read from a excel file in every iteration so cant be concatenated. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to write all of the command strings to a `.bat` or `.cmd` file, and then execute the resulting file with `os.system`.

This is more useful if the number of commands per iteration is "large-ish" and less useful if there are only a few commands per iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to execute this command in a remote machine, then you may consider using Paramiko. I have personally found it very useful and it lets you execute the command as root also.